# Is line by line reading really not supported by node?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a clone of UNIX's `cat` in node. One thing that I don't get is why there is no proper way to read a file line by line. I looked at various modules that claim to offer that, but under the hood they all do the same:

```
var lines = s.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
```

(Taken from node's [readline](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/4a90f51bfe9934048520f6a3ffb717fc7ddbe843/lib/readline.js#L867)).

While that does work, it is a terrible solution that wastes a lot of resources. But why doesn't node support such a basic use case? Or does it and I'm just overlooking something?

Comment: How do you suspect other languages do it internally without splitting strings on newlines, and why would those methods be more efficient in your opinion ?

Comment: If you really mean reading files partially, Node does support that with buffers.

Comment: `readline` is a lib for interacting with a tty (modeled on http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), so its not even close to what you're looking for.  I'll give you that the name is confusing, though.

Comment: @adeneo I assume they read char by char and split on newline instead of reading the entire file and then iterating it again. But I might be wrong about how big the performance difference actually is.

Comment: @AaronDufour I looked into readline because of a blog post that suggested using it for this purpose. Since it emits a `line` event it would actually work, but my issue with it applies to a few other modules from npm as well that were actually made for reading a file line by line.

Comment: @jgillich Yes, it does emit a `line` event, but since its focus is on ttys rather than files, I wouldn't have expected it to be efficient at what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll this yourself without too much trouble.  The best way to do it is probably using [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).  You can get a stream of a file with:

```
fs.createReadStream(filename)
```

Now, we'll define a type of `Transform` that breaks input into lines:

```
class LineBreak extends stream.Transform
  constructor: ->
    @_rem = "\n"
    super

  _transform: (chunk, encoding, next) ->
    @_rem += chunk.toString()
    while (ixNewline = @_rem.indexOf('\n', 1)) > 0
      @push(@_rem.slice(1, ixNewline))
      @_rem = @_rem.slice(ixNewline)
    next()

  _flush: (next) ->
    if @_rem.length > 0
      @push(@_rem.slice(1))
    next()
```

This is CoffeeScript, which I'm a lot more comfortable writing.  The compiled JavaScript is lengthy and not particularly idiomatic, but you can easily compile it [here](http://coffeescript.org/).  However, I think the CoffeeScript version gets the point across.

Example usage:

```
lb = new LineBreak()
file.pipe(lb).pipe(process.stdout)
```

You'll notice that it spits out the appropriate file with newlines stripped.